# Docker-compose --isolation=hyperv tag

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyper-v

I have to use the --isolation=hyperv configuration when I bringing up my container (using windows server 17.09).

for example:

```
 docker run -it -d -p 2222:80 --isolation=hyperv packagelocatorservice
```

I need to bring up 4 containers, so I am using docker-compose.yml file
and the command                                                                                                      `docker-compose up`

```
version: '3'

services:

web:
image: web
ports:
- 4444:80
build:
context: ./web/webapi
dockerfile: Dockerfile

uimetadataservice:
image: uimetadataservice
ports:
- 1111:80
build:
context: ./MetaDataService
dockerfile: Dockerfile

packagelocatorservice:
image: packagelocatorservice
ports:
- 2222:80
build:
context: ./PackageLocatorService/PackageLocatorService
dockerfile: Dockerfile

assetmanagementserviceweb:
image: assetmanagementserviceweb
ports:
- 3333:80
build:
context: ./InfrastructureWebService
dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Any ideas if I can add the --isolation=hyperv tag inside the docker-compose file?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: @Kieron Could not find anything related to answer this

Comment: nothing. We're currently moving over to Service Fabric, with Docker Compose as the configuration. None of this is ideal.

Windows Containers are too big and too slow currently, but we don't have a choice without a complete re-write for some older components.

Our newer code is all .NET Core, so runs brilliantly on Linux Containers via Docker Compose.

Answer (score 2):

This commit may have added support for this:
https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5448/commits/8155ddc7add99edd1c9a366f44c65ba4d62589a3

I have updated the version to 3.5 and added `isolation: 'hyperv'` below images in web hope this works for you.

```
version: '3.5'

services:

web:
image: web
isolation: 'hyperv'
ports:
- 4444:80
build:
context: ./web/webapi
dockerfile: Dockerfile

uimetadataservice:
image: uimetadataservice
ports:
- 1111:80
build:
context: ./MetaDataService
dockerfile: Dockerfile

packagelocatorservice:
image: packagelocatorservice
ports:
- 2222:80
build:
context: ./PackageLocatorService/PackageLocatorService
dockerfile: Dockerfile

assetmanagementserviceweb:
image: assetmanagementserviceweb
ports:
- 3333:80
build:
context: ./InfrastructureWebService
dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

It's worth noting I was not able to mix and match different isolations